# End of file Rspec error with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test that I can `POST` a survey via AJAX

Test code:

```
describe "when completing the survey" do
    before do
        visit "/orders/#{@order.disguised_id}?key=#{ENV['admin_code']}"
        find("#show-survey").click
        find(".modal#survey-box select[name='heard']").find("[value='Other']").select_option
        find("#submit-survey").click
    end

    it "should submit correctly" do
        @order.reload
        @order.heard.should == "Other"
    end
    # test post survey
end
```

First off, I can confirm via manual testing that this works. The issue is that the spec fails:

```
  1)  when completing the survey should submit correctly
 Failure/Error: find("#submit-survey").click
 EOFError:
   end of file reached
 # ./spec/features/edit_order/editing_order_spec.rb:<<the line with find("#submit-suvery")>>
```

When it fails, the Rspec auto ends the run and I'm left with an open browser window (using Selenium) and a regular command line interface. This is the controller that receives the `POST`

```
def survey
    @order = Order.find_by_disguised_id(order_params[:disguised_id])
    @order.update_attributes(order_params)
    render nothing: true
end
```

Comment: What browser are you using with selenium - and what versions of the relevant gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using chrome with selenium make sure you're running the latest version of chromedriver (2.24 as of this answer).

Additionally - click is asynchronous so reloading the order immediately after clicking #submit-survey is going to be flaky at best since it's highly likely it will be reloading @order before the ajax request is processed.  You need to wait for whatever visual change on the page would indicate the survey has been submitted after clicking.

```
find("#submit-survey").click
page.should have_text('something') # whatever shows up when the survey finishes submitting - or use have_css, etc
```

Also the previous line `find(".modal#survey-box select[name='heard']").find("[value='Other']").select_option` can be written in a more readable manner as

```
find(".modal#survey-box").select('Other', from: 'heard')
```